# Spring SAML 2.0 in Spring boot application causing NullPointerException in MetadataManager while bringing up embedded tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, saml-2.0

Implemented Spring boot application with SAML 2.0 using these versions:
Spring Boot - 2.2.5.RELEASE
SAML 2.0 - 1.0.1.RELEASE

Implemented as per the spring documentations but using annotations instead of xml configuration

Exceptions:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.getTrustEngine(MetadataManager.java:607) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.10.RELEASE.jar:1.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.initializeProviderFilters(MetadataManager.java:549) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.10.RELEASE.jar:1.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.refreshMetadata(MetadataManager.java:263) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.10.RELEASE.jar:1.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager.refreshMetadata(CachingMetadataManager.java:86) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.10.RELEASE.jar:1.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.afterPropertiesSet(MetadataManager.java:168) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.10.RELEASE.jar:1.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
```

Comment: any luck with this?  Running into the same issue after following the Spring Boot SAML Guide (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-saml)